# Code compare and merge tool for Mac OSX

Tags: gratis, osx, diff, source-code

Any recommended tools, which can do in-place (for in-place, I mean some IDE or tools which could have functions of both compare and merge.) compare for two files, and merge them in-place?

I currently use the diff command line, but am looking for a GUI tool.

Free tool is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some suggestions:

- FileMerge (`opendiff`)

  It's no longer bundled with Xcode Command Line Tools, you must install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) from either the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835) or the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/download/).
- [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
- [Pretty Diff](https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff/)

  Open sourced beautifier and language aware code comparison tool for many languages.
- [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)

  Can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via command: `brew install meld`
- [TkDiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/)

  Can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via command: `brew install tkdiff`
- [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/)
- [VisualDiffer](http://visualdiffer.com/)

  Available at App Store
- [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/)

  Commercial with free trial.
- [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en)

  Commercial with free trial.
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)

  No longer in Homebrew, it has not been developed/updated since 2014.

Related posts:

- [Comparison of file comparison tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) at Wikipedia
- [What file comparison tool can I use under OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10099/22781) [closed]
- [What's a good Mac equivalent of WinMerge?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3653/22781) [closed]
- [Portable, free, cross-platform, GUI-based prose-friendly plain-text diff and merge tool?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50885/3474)
- [Graphical diff programs for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112932/55075)

Comment: For me `Meld` is the best tool for Mac and Windows. Thanks

Comment: Might be worth updating TextWrangler (now discontinued) with [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html). Its diff tool is excellent, though under documented. [Screenshot](https://www.barebones.com/images/bbedit/diff-results-lg.png), described in some detail [here, about half-way down](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/04/14/comparing-files-filemerge-opendiff-and-bbedit/), and also has a command-line call: `bbdiff --ignore-spaces "./path/to/file1.txt" "./path/to/file2.txt"` Works in free mode too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112932/graphical-diff-programs-for-linux) StackOverflow question. Might be what you asked for.

Comment: Nice recommendation Abdul, vote up, will try and see any further issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are already working with code then I recommend [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) since it has an excellent built-in diff tool. Visual Studio Code is a pretty good code editor in its own right so I think it's a good app to have installed along with your other development tools. I use it to work on miscellaneous projects outside of my main IDE.

To use its compare feature, you first need two files open. Then, from the explorer panel, right click the first file and click "Select for Compare". Then, from the explorer panel, right click the second file and click "Compare with Selected". A new tab will open which shows the two files side by side with differences highlighted.

Here is an example of the difference view:

[image: Visual Studio Code Difference Editor]

Conveniently, you can also launch the difference view from the command line. Based on the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options), it looks like you can launch it like this:

```
code -d /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

or

```
code --diff /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```