# Portable, free, cross-platform, GUI-based prose-friendly plain-text diff and merge tool?

Tags: cross-platform, version-control, portable, diff, utility

I have a Macbook at home and a GNU/linux desktop workstation at work. But, I sometimes also have to work on my university's library machines (running Windows 7) without admin rights.

Is there a (preferably open-source), but certainly **free** (as in free beer), cross-platform *GUI-based* plain-text diff-tool that will work on at least these three platforms (Win 7 & 10, GNU Linux, MacOS 10.13)? For Windows machines, this must work without **admin priveleges**.

#### Viable option until now: VimDiff

I did an exhaustive research of options before posting this question. The only viable tool I could find was `vimdiff` (i.e. the diff-mode within vim) that truly satisfies all criteria (GUI available, free, open-source, cross-platform). The amazing `fugitive.vim` plugin by the legendary tpope also brings in git-based diff and 3-way merging to within vim. Now, while I am very comfortable with vim, since I need to also work on friends' machines to view diffs on a collaborative project, I do not want to force them to learn vim. Furthemore, since we are presently working on prose (a paper being written in latex) rather than code, I think a word-based diff-tool, rather than a line-based one shall be helpful.

#### Possible cue: Java based

A majority of machines I work on have a working JRE installed. So, even if a true multi-platform native desktop application is not available, an app distributed as a portable `jar` file which runs atop a standard JVM/JRE should be good enough. I found `jedit` which has a diff plugin. But even this asks for an install to the restricted `C:\program_files(x86)` location on Windows. I am looking for something which works akin to `jabref` which is a brilliant reference management software distributed as a cross-platform standalone `jar` file.

#### Possible cue2: Tcl/Tk based alternatives

The TCL/TK framework seems to be yet another way to go portable. I found `tkdiff` which seems to be well-maintained. But, my univeristy's library machines do not have `TCL/TK` framework installed on Win 7. I tried clicking around `freewrap` but cannot figure out how to use it. Any help in this direction is also welcome.

#### Note on web-based alternatives

[`prettydiff`](http://prettydiff.com/) is a viable browser-based alternative that ticks all required boxes. But since we do not like to upload any source-component of our project on the web (despite any privacy promises), a standalone desktop application becomes essential. Such web-based tools cannot also handle git repos, and is good for just a quick one-off diff, rather than as part of a systematic workflow.

**PS:** Git or other vcs-diff capabilities will be a bonus.

Comment: I tried `alacritty` and `wizterm` and was underwhelmed. `kitty` didn't even work on Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrettyDiff is CC0 licensed -

> "Pretty Diff project, as of version 2.1.17 and all following versions
>   unless otherwise changed, is licensed with a Creative Commons 1.0
>   Universal license (CC0)."

Why not grab source and run it on your own machine or on a VPS?

Website: http://prettydiff.com/

GitHub: https://github.com/prettydiff/prettydiff

Comment: This seems to be an NPM project? The computers I work with don't have nodejs installed. Maybe there is a portable version of a node-compatible JavaScript engine I can use.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/). From the ["About"](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/about.html) page:

> Diffuse is a small and simple text merge tool written in Python.
>
> Diffuse should run on any POSIX operating system, including Mac OS X,
>   with the following packages installed:
>
> ```
> Python >= 2.4
> PyGTK >= 2.10
> ```
>
> Pre-built packages for Microsoft Windows include all dependencies.

Development has stopped in 2014, though.

Comment: Aah. Diffuse seems to be good. Thanks for the pointer. I do hate bitrot. After all, nobody can write bug-free code in a major project, plus there are always improvements to polish various things. Even sporadic development would be understandable in a mature project, but complete abandonment is not a good sign.

Comment: This does not answer the use case in my question. It is not a self-contained portable application. When I downloaded the exe file on my library computer, it popped up the admin prompt.

Comment: Maybe some of the GUI toolkits are missing. don't know how to install them as non-admin user on windows.

Answer (score 1):

When I need portability I generally look to perl. For example, on a Mac:

```
$ head z1 z2 ; ./diff.pl z1 z2
==> z1 <==
hi

==> z2 <==
bye
1c1
< hi
---
> bye
```

Here are some details:

```
diff.pl Display differences in text files, perl version. (what)
Path    : ~/bin/diff.pl
Version : - ( local: ~/bin/diff.pl, 2009-10-22 )
Length  : 729 lines
Type    : Perl script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/perl
Modules : (for perl codes)
 strict 1.08
 Carp   1.3301
 Algorithm::Diff        1.1902
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Apple/BSD, Darwin 17.6.0, x86_64
Distribution        : macOS 10.13.5 (17F77), High Sierra
diff.pl - ( local: ./diff.pl, 2018-07-01 )
```

And diff.pl can be found at cpan.org: [perl version of diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PerlPowerTools/bin/diff) You'll need perl on Windows; I have not tried that recently.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: Thank you. Yes. There is official strawberryperl portable for Windows. I need to mention that I am looking for graphical (GUI-based) diffing and merging, as vimdiff (diff mode within vim) is already available and portable editions of vim are already available on windows. With ```fugitive.vim``` plugin, git diffs are no problem as well.  I shall update the question accordingly to narrow down the scope. I am really sorry about this.